# Image Shadow Removal Using OpenCV and Python

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python, opencv

How do I remove a shadow after MOG2 background subtraction using OpenCV Python? I used all morphological operations, gaussian and median blur, thresholding. it removes noises but deep shadow is resulting in foreground object.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(128,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,1)
masked_image = fgbg.apply(image)
```

in masked_image shadow will be grey color(pixel value= 127)
just replace 127 to 0, to convert grey pixel to black.

```
masked_image[masked_image==127]=0
```

Comment: I have same problem. Is there any suggestion for stile image?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has many different Background subtraction models.

If you use: `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG` it will produce foreground without any shadows.

If you use: `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` it will produce foreground with shadows included. However, they are grey color.

So if you look at the foreground mask - following rule applies:

`pixel[i][j] == 0   --> background`
`pixel[i][j] == 256 --> foreground`
`else pixel[i][j] == anyother value --> shadow.`

See [this for reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html).